# Can IEnumerable.Count() return a negative number?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The C# `IEnumerable.Count(IEnumerable<TSource>)` and `IEnumerable.Count(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,Boolean>)` both return type `int` implying it can return a value less than zero. It doesn't make sense for it to do so, but if the type is `int` it's theoretically possible for the result to be a negative value.

```cs
IEnumerable<string> list = GetMyList(); 
int listCount = list.Count(); 

// is it more correct to do this: 
if(listCount <= 0)
{
    DoSomething(); 
} 
else 
{
    DoSomethingElse(); 
} 

// or this: 
if(listCount == 0)
{
    DoSomething(); 
} 
else if (listCount > 0)
{
    DoSomethingElse(); 
} 
else 
{
    // but this branch will never be hit 
    throw new Exception(); 
}
```

I can't find any information online about whether or not that can actually happen, and the [Documentation for Enumerable.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) does not specify any cases in which it might.

Just wondering if anyone has any experience with this happening or any information on this.

Thanks

Comment: Related: [Why does .NET use `int` instead of `uint` in certain classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/782629/150605), [Why is `Array.Length` an `int`, and not an `uint`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6301/150605)

Comment: Could it return a negative? Yes. Would it ever return a negative? *Very* unlikely. It's possible that there's some implementation of `IEnumerable` where it makes sense but I can't think of where it would be useful. Perhaps in some streaming context like reactive extensions.

Comment: Interesting - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035875/can-you-have-negative-sets

Comment: How would you interpret a negative number for ["Returns the number of elements in a sequence."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) as anything other than a bug?

Comment: Only way that happens is if you have something that implements `ICollection<T>` that returns a negative value for it's `Count` property as `Enumerable.Count` will use that if it can.  Otherwise it attempts to iteratethe `IEnumerable` and counts from 0 the number of items.

Comment: I worry about this sometimes. Perhaps a short course in Common Sense is called for.

Comment: So, again, how would you interpret a negative number for ["Gets the number of elements contained in the ICollection<T>"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.count?view=netframework-4.7.1) as anything other than a bug? An interface specification carries more of a contract than the compiler-enforced signature.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of the return data type is not to imply a range of numbers. Although it naturally does set a hard upper and lower limit (sort of... see [LongCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548914(v=vs.110).aspx)), that is just a side effect of type compatibility and generalizability.

Consider the Array's [Rank](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.rank(v=vs.110).aspx) property. The maximum value is 32. But we don't store it in a byte or short. We store it in an int. Why? We don't *need* all that range. But it's recommended: they're fast (they align well to register size and memory maps) and, by convention, [It is easier to work with other libraries if you work with ints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions). Also, the `int` datatype is [CLS-compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301/why-is-array-length-an-int-and-not-an-uint) (meaning that any language that implements the CLR must support it) but `uint32` is not.

Returning a numeric data type that has a particular range in no way implies that the full range will be used. And returning a negative value from `IEnumerable.Count()` would not only be poor form, but it would be semantically incorrect, as a count must obviously return a [cardinal number](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136366/has-negative-cardinality-been-considered), which must be and integer and non-negative.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there´s no such method `Count` defined on neither `IEnumerable` nor `IEnumerable<T>`, but on the static class `System.Linq.Enumerable`. As it´s a (`static`) extension-method, you can´t override nor modify this at all. So let´s look into the extension-method:

```
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    ICollection<TSource> collectionoft = source as ICollection<TSource>;
    if (collectionoft != null) return collectionoft.Count;
    ICollection collection = source as ICollection;
    if (collection != null) return collection.Count;

    int count = 0;
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
        checked {
            while (e.MoveNext()) count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

As you can see the only way `Count` will *ever* return a negative number is by implelementing `ICollection.Count`, which is called by `Enumerable.Count()` (as you can see above), or by creating your own extension-method with the exact same name and relying on [extension-method resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698864/extension-method-priority) in order to "hide" the method from `System.Linq.Enumerable`:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static int Count(this IEnumerable<T> src) { return -1; }
}
```

However I can´t see any reason why one should do this at all.

So in short the method *can* return a negative number. Doing this however breaks the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and thus is a bad idea.

Comment: _"So the method may never return a negative number."_ -    It returns an Int which last time I checked is **signed**

Comment: You're just showing the extensions of `IEnumerable`, its entirely possible a third party library has implemented it's own count that does return a negative number.

Comment: @DavidG `Count` isn´t even defined on the interface itself, only on the static class `Enumerable`. So the only way that´ll work is by creating your own extension-method for this and *not* including `System.Linq`, or do I miss anything?

Comment: I'm just saying it's not so simple. For example, the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) state: *If the type of source implements ICollection<T>, that implementation is used to obtain the count of elements. Otherwise, this method determines the count.*

Comment: For example, [see here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L1305) which is the code tht determines what method to call to get a count. That could be a custom `ICollection<T>` implementation.

Comment: Perhaps some demo code would explain it better https://dotnetfiddle.net/9od6Si This shows you don't need to "hide" anything as you say.

Comment: You don't even need to hack with collection or not including LINQ if you just concerned about `.Count()` returning -1 (and not `IEnumerable<T>.Count` in particular) - non-generic `Count` extension method or method of custom type will be preferred over generic one... `static int Count(this MyEnumerableType t) { return -42;}`

Comment: This is a prickly one to vote on; the difference between what a method _can_ return and what it (likely) _should_ return.  Considering the two ways to make `Count()` return a negative number are both somewhat evil, I give @HimBromBeere the benefit of the doubt and vote +0.  Still, the answer to "Can `IEnumerable.Count()` return a negative number?" (that is, "Can `IEnumerable.Count()` _be made to_ return a negative number?") is clearly "Yes".

Comment: If you go to all the effort of creating a replacement/preferred `Count()` method, we're not really talking about the same `IEnumerable.Count(IEnumerable<TSource>)` anymore though, are we?

Comment: @ZacFaragher Yes we are because the `ICollection` implementation of it gets called internally.

Comment: I got down-voted for saying "no, it doesn't return a negative number", for not factoring in someone hacking and making it do so. I felt the question was more about why uint is not used to enforce a positive count.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 Actually you got downvoted for your answer being mostly incorrect.

Comment: @DavidG However this assumes we *implement* `ICollection`. For other enumerables we can´t modify the behaviour at all (unless we rely on the hack of "hiding" I mentioned earlier).

Comment: But you're assuming it *isn't* implemented. The point is that it could be and because we're talking about an interface, not a concrete class, we can't be sure what it contains. For example, what would `Count` return for something like a network stream? In theory it would either never return or (more sensibly) throw an error. We often get too caught up in thinking about enumerables as finite lists of things but in reality they can be all sort of weird and wonderful things.

Comment: @DavidG If all we have is an `IEnumerable` I can´t see any way around the extension-method apart from those mentioned above. So even if your own implementation for `IEumerable` has its own `Count`-method, it´ll never be called, as seen in [my fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jQNWqC). Instead the extension-method is called which depends on if `ICollection` is also implemented.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 I understood you to be referring to [CLS-compliance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/language-independence-and-language-independent-components).