# Why I am getting an error "The type arguments for method 'method' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly"?

Tags: c#

I have data reader extension class:

```
public static class SqlDataReaderExtensions
{
        public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IDataReader reader)
        {
            var list = new List<T>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

                foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    if (!Equals(reader[prop.Name], DBNull.Value))
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(obj, reader[prop.Name], null);
                    }
                }

                list.Add(obj);
            }

            return list;
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(this IDataReader reader, Func<IDataReader, T> projection)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                yield return projection(reader);
            }
        }
}
```

I am using it like this:

```
public async Task<IList<Department>> GetAllAsync(int pageIndex, int pageSize, string keyword, bool shared)
{
    var parameters = new[]
            {
                new SqlParameter("@Keyword", SqlDbType.NVarChar) {Value = keyword},
                new SqlParameter("@PageIndex", SqlDbType.Int) {Value = pageIndex},
                new SqlParameter("@PageSize", SqlDbType.Int) {Value = pageSize},
                new SqlParameter("@Shared", SqlDbType.Bit) {Value = shared},
            };

    using (var reader = await SqlHelper.ExecuteReaderAsync(_connectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetAllDepartments", parameters))
    {
        return reader.Select(r =>
                {
                    var p = new Department
                    {
                        Id = (int)r["ID"],
                        Name = r["Name"].ToString(),
                        Type = r["Type"].ToString()
                    };

                    return p;
                }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: The function is declared `List<T> ToList<T>(this IDataReader reader)`.  The type `T` is not deducible from the the arguments, so you must explicitly declare it when you use it.  Call it this way: `.ToList<Department>()`.  I don't think you need to do it for `Select`, since the type `T` should be deducible from the type of the delegate you pass in

Comment: IT IS WORKING IN ANOTHER CLASS WITH THE SAME THING

Comment: @user123456 You have defined an extension method `ToList<T>()` for the type `IDataReader`, but your custom `Select<T>()` extension is returning a `IEnumerable<T>`. That will not fit. And it is using **that** extension method (and not from  `System.Linq.Enumerable`) most likely because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698864/extension-method-priority. A simple `using System.Linq;` might fix the issue.

Comment: @Progman yhanks

Answer (score 0):

The `ToList()` method you are using after the `Select` is the `System.Linq.Enumerable` method and not the method you have written above.

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) => source != null ? new List<TSource>(source) : throw Error.ArgumentNull(nameof (source));
```